# Diagonal difference of two columns in Pandas Dataframe based on unique IDs and plot graph

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    videoId viewedMinutes   totalMinutes    user_drop   TotalUsers
    1017479     0                5             8         34
    1017479     1                5             3         34
    1017479     2                5             2         34
    1017479     4                5             3         34
    1017479     5                5             19        34
    1036704     0                16            1         14
    1036704     1                16            2         14
    1036704     2                16            2         14
    1036704     3                16            1         14
    1036704     5                16            1         14
    1036704     6                16            1         14
    1036704     8                16            2         14
```

So I want to create a new columns `active_users` minute wise, which will look something like this:

```
    videoId viewedMinutes  totalMinutes   user_drop TotalUsers active_users
    1017479     0                5             8         34       34 (1st is fixed)
    1017479     1                5             3         34       26(34(active_users)-8(user_drop))
    1017479     2                5             2         34       23(26-3)
    1017479     4                5             3         34       21(23-2)
    1017479     5                5             18        34       18(21-3)
    1036704     0                16            1         14       14
    1036704     1                16            2         14       12
    1036704     2                16            2         14       10
    1036704     3                16            1         14       9
    1036704     5                16            1         14       8
    1036704     6                16            1         14       7
    1036704     8                16            6         14       6
```

So its like diagonally subtracting, but 1st and last values will remain fixed. Also I want this algorithm to run for each unique `videoId` and not throughout my dataframe.

Now with `for` loop I want to plot a scatter plot for each unique `videoId` in plotly, having minutes in X-axis and no. of active users in the Y-axis. The graph will look something like this: [retention.jpg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18P4T6cevBfBy87IE8XQT_6Mx3Kj2uOR4)

Comment: `viewedMinutes` and `totalMinutes` columns should be ignored? Or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) - for each first row is created `NaN` value, which is ignored by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) function with parameter `fill_value=0`:

```
s = df.groupby('videoId')['user_drop'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift())
df['active'] = df['TotalUsers'].sub(s, fill_value=0).astype(int)
print (df)
    videoId  viewedMinutes  totalMinutes  user_drop  TotalUsers  active
0   1017479              0             5          8          34      34
1   1017479              1             5          3          34      26
2   1017479              2             5          2          34      23
3   1017479              4             5          3          34      21
4   1017479              5             5         19          34      18
5   1036704              0            16          1          14      14
6   1036704              1            16          2          14      13
7   1036704              2            16          2          14      11
8   1036704              3            16          1          14       9
9   1036704              5            16          1          14       8
10  1036704              6            16          1          14       7
11  1036704              8            16          2          14       6
```

EDIT:

For scatter plot use:

```
for i, df in df.groupby('videoId'):
    ax = df.plot.scatter(x='viewedMinutes', y='active')
    ax.set_title(i, fontsize=20)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked out. I'll accept your answer after 12 minutes. And just one thing I have added in the question regarding plotting can you please help me out with that.

Comment: @DebadriDutta - Sure, can you explain more what columns need plot?

Comment: @DebadriDutta - So here is problem for each group need separately plot like `df.groupby('videoId').plot(x='viewedMinutes', y='active')` ?

Comment: It is pandas plot. Do yiou need for each group separately plot?

Comment: yes I need for each trail Id and that too in plotly. Can you check once the link of the `rention.jpg` I've mentioned in my answer, and update your answer, please.

Comment: Sorry, now checked.

Comment: and also please can you explain the functioning of the `cumsum.shift()` part, please

Comment: @DebadriDutta - Yes. For each group are created cumulative sum of `user_drop` columns and then this values are shift - last value is lost and first value is `NaN` for each group.

Comment: Can i do it for plotly?

Comment: @DebadriDutta - Do you think something like [this](https://plot.ly/pandas/time-series/) ?

Comment: yes something like the last graph. And also in the `for` loop plot that you have mentioned, its plotting only first graph, no graphs after that

Comment: @DebadriDutta - I try a lot, but never use `plotly` before :( So sorry, I dont know what it should be best solution. I also test [this](https://plot.ly/pandas/filled-area-plots/), but cannot working with your solution.

Comment: @DebadriDutta - so if possible, can you post new question about ploting by plotly? And add my last code, what you try ;)

Comment: in that for loop, scatter plot that you have mentioned, its plotting only for the first unique trail id, after that its not plotting anything

Comment: Hi, just to update you, it was my part of mistake, for loop is plotting all the plots